# model.fit_generator() fails with use_multiprocessing=True

Tags: tensorflow, keras, multiprocessing, generator

In the code example below, I can train the model only when NOT using multiprocessing.

My generator is straight from the tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence description https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence

Any idea how to fix the generator to allow multiprocessing?

Running on Win 10, tensorflow 1.13.1, python 3.6.8

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence


# Generator
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

        def __init__(self, dim, batch_size, n_channels):

            self.dim = dim            
            self.batch_size = batch_size
            self.n_channels = n_channels

        def __len__(self):
            return 100

        def __getitem__(self, idx):

            X = np.random.randn(self.batch_size, self.dim, self.n_channels)
            Y = np.random.randn(self.batch_size, self.dim, 1)

            return X, Y


dim= 32
batch_size= 64
n_channels= 3

# Generators
training_generator = DataGenerator(dim, batch_size, n_channels)
validation_generator = DataGenerator(dim, batch_size, n_channels)


# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=True, 
                     batch_input_shape=[None, training_generator.dim, training_generator.n_channels]))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')


# This training procedure runs
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    epochs = 2,
                    steps_per_epoch = 100,
                    max_queue_size = 32,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps = 20,
                    verbose=1)

# This training procedure fails (Only change is that I added the multiprocessing options)
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    epochs = 2,
                    steps_per_epoch = 100,
                    max_queue_size = 32,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    validation_steps = 20,
                    verbose=1,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    workers=4)
```

I expected the second fit_generator() call to train the model like the first one. Instead, I get no output, not even an error message.

Comment: Have you checked your GPU's. Windows may have some problems with nccl library

Comment: My GPU (and CPU for that matter...) don't show activity in Task Manager. The last output I get is "Epoch 1/2" and then nothing... Any idea for a fix if it actually is the nccl library?

Comment: It was just a guess, if you're running on CPU nccl wouldn't matter

Comment: Ah sorry, that was unclear. I am running it on a GPU. I meant that my CPU doesn't show activity either, even though they should both be busy...

Comment: try setting `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.configproto(allow_soft_placement=true))
tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but didn't change anything. Also by now, I do get "sine waves" of GPU and CPU activity, but still no output (I didn't change the code, just rebooted)...

Comment: you  get system halt or just python app?

Comment: just python app (I use anaconda & spyder)

Comment: Than you may search github for package compatibility issues

Comment: Try to write `DataGenerator` without deriving from `Sequence`.

Comment: Hi @SimonSchmickler, have you found a solution to this problem? I am having similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS machine with python 3.6.8 and tensorflow 1.13.1. It works in both cases as log shown below:

```
2019-07-13 12:56:17.003119: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:152] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.10.0 locally
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 27ms/step - loss: 0.9987
100/100 [==============================] - 10s 103ms/step - loss: 0.9973 - val_loss: 0.9987
Epoch 2/2
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 26ms/step - loss: 0.9955
100/100 [==============================] - 8s 83ms/step - loss: 1.0028 - val_loss: 0.9955
Multiprocessing=True ......
Epoch 1/2
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 32ms/step - loss: 0.9952
100/100 [==============================] - 9s 89ms/step - loss: 0.9962 - val_loss: 0.9952
Epoch 2/2
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 28ms/step - loss: 0.9967
100/100 [==============================] - 9s 86ms/step - loss: 0.9968 - val_loss: 0.9967"
```

My suggestion is to first try with CPU only mode, by putting BOTH the model and the fit_generator code under  "with tf.device('/cpu:0'):". If it works, it would be GPU related issue, such as proper driver, tensorflow with GPU support etc. Most likely, the issue was caused by GPU hanging.